# I am trying to output information from <form> using append in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My first question:

It's our first discussion about javascript in my college and our teacher gave us a homework to
output info from  using append in javascript. I studied some of it in w3schools but can't seem to get a hang of it yet. Our homework is about a registration form and if you fill in the fields and hit the button, it will display the information below the registration form.
I have started my homework but I can't seem to finish it and get it right. I want the individual infos to be displayed like blocks, but instead they are in the same line separated by a space. I am not yet familiar with append, it would be great if anyone can
tell the right method for my homework.

here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Registration</title>

<style>

    #main{
    border:3px solid green;
    background:silver;
    width:350px;
    padding:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:100px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    color:blue;
    }

    #register{
    font-size:20px;
    }

</style>

<script>

function displayInfo(){
        var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var mname = document.getElementById("mname").value;
        var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;


        var info=uname+'\n'+pass+'\n'+fname+'\n'+mname+'\n'+lname;
        var t=document.createTextNode(info);

        document.body.appendChild(t);
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="main">
        <p id="register">Registration</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="username" size="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" id="password" size="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Firstname</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fname" size="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Middlename</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="mname" size="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Lastname</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="lname" size="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Sex</td>
                <td>
                Guy
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" size="20" value="guy">
                Gal
                <input type="radio" id="radio2" size="20" value="gal">
                Other
                <input type="radio" id="radio3" size="20" value="other">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Program</td>
                <td>
                It
                <input type="checkbox" id="check1" size="20" value="It">
                Cba
                <input type="checkbox" id="check2" size="20" value="Cba">
                Hosm
                <input type="checkbox" id="check3" size="20" value="Hosm">
                Other
                <input type="checkbox" id="check4" size="20" value="other">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"                                          
                 onCLick="displayInfo()">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>



   </body>
   </html>
```

My second question:

About the radios and check boxes, I want it to display the value whenever one of it is clicked. I have found some answer here in stack but I don't know how to implement it in my code. The answer from another question goes like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
rate_value = document.getElementById('r1').value;
}
```

I have no idea how to implement this in my code, I have tried it but it won't display anything.

PS.

I'm not allowed to use jquery yet since it's our first discussion about javascript.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Append a `<p>` that contains the text instead of only the text on its own for creating blocks.

Comment: rate_value should be an html control (ie. a place where you can display information on a page), and not a variable which the user won't be able to see

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried to use the `.checked` boolean property in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to avoid logic in the markup. Using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) is a much better and scalable solution. If your using IE < 9 then your stuck using awkward and obsolete code that is difficult to maintain (find a good bar and become a regular patron).

Check boxes are strange in that they don't act like regular form elements. You have to manually construct the appropriate values. By naming the boxes the same we can loop over them and find their `checked` value. Radio and checkboxes are handled differently.

### Radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="foobar" value="fooVal">
<input type="radio" name="foobar" value="barVal" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="foobar" value="bazVal">
```

The JavaScript (ECMAScript 5:

```
var checkedValue = (function(domList) {
  var value;
  Array.prototype.some.call(domList, function(checkBox) {
    if (checkBox.checked) {
      value = checkBox.value;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  return value;
})(document.getElementsByName('foobar'));
```

### Check Boxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foobar" value="fooVal">
<input type="checkbox" name="foobar" value="barVal" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="foobar" value="bazVal">
```

The JavaScript (ECMAScript 5:

```
var checkedValues = (function(domList) {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(domList, function(checkBox) {
    if (checkBox.checked) {
      return checkBox.value;
    }
  })
  .filter(function(value) {
    return (value != null);
  });
})(document.getElementsByName('foobar'));

// You can then comma delimit...
var strValues = checkedValues.join(', ');
```

A working example is at http://jsbin.com/vewayi/2/edit

Finally, I might note that the process of fetching the values in general could be DRY'ed up as in the example here: http://jsbin.com/vewayi/4/edit

Comment: Thank You! this is exaclty what I was  looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The first code [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/S8Qk7/). As for the second question, you'll want to attach an `onclick` handler for each radio button:

```
document.getElementById('radio1').onchange = function() {
    // do your stuff here
}
//etc...
```

and checkbox:

```
document.getElementById('check1').onchange = function() {
    // do your stuff here
}
//etc...
```

Comment: Hi! I have tried work code and it seems to work well. What if I want the radio value to display when the submit button is click so that it will output with the other information altogether? Thanks for your help btw!